# stat_compare_means() gives different p.value than compare_means() or t.test()

Tags: r, ggpubr

I would like to plot data with ggplot2 and add p-values using ggpubr. But the plotted p-values don't match the p-values I calculate with `compare_means()` or `t.test()`.

This is my data:

```
Group <- rep(c('A'), each=12)
Drug <- rep(c('x','y'), each= 6)
RC <- c(13076,  10814,  14297,  13119,  13616,  5, 19671,   18318,  12058,  17624,  9565,   13689)
mydf <- as.data.frame(cbind(Group,Drug,RC))
mydf$RC <- as.numeric(as.character(mydf$RC))
```

This is the code for the plot:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
ggplot(mydf, aes(x=factor(Group),y=log10(RC)))+
geom_boxplot(aes(color=Drug))+stat_compare_means(aes(group = Drug), method = "t.test", label = "p.format")
```

The p.value displayed is p=0.32. However, when I use other method to calculate the p.value I get this ~0.149

```
compare_means(RC~Drug,data=mydf, method = "t.test")

t.test(RC~Drug,data=mydf, exact= FALSE)
```

A similar issue has been adressed [here](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/34), but in this case `compare_means()`, gave another result, compared to `stat_compare_means()` and `t.test()`. I  made sure to have the most recent version of ggpubr (ggpubr_0.1.6.999).

What is it that am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a test on the log value:

```
t.test(log10(RC) ~ Drug, data = mydf, exact = FALSE)
# 0.3237
```

Comment: If if was helpful, it would be great if you would accept the answer, thanks.

Comment: This was very helpful :) How do I "accept" your answers? I'm sorry I was not aware that I have to do that?

Comment: There is a check box you can click beside the answer.